# drupal 7 easy edit footer message without editing the php files

Tags: drupal-7, footer

Drupal 7 specific [as, apparently (from Google results) that it was different in drupal 6 and earlier, and things might change in future.]

Have a drupal install where I want to add an editable footer without changing the tpl source files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved it https://drupal.org/project/footer_message downloaded the code from [ftp](http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/footer_message-7.x-1.1.tar.gz) 
On install as promised got a configurable footer message, editable from the site-information form and displayed as a block.

Using the footer message in a block is best. Download and enable the module as you would any other. it has no options. then head over to edit the footer message --> http://your-site.com/admin/config/system/site-information choose html or php, enter contents.
* The footer message block can be placed on your site via the block administration screen